# Statistical test & visualization type for associations between symptoms, and chosen treatment

Tags: r, clustering, networks

I have a dataset with symptoms and its severity (integer: 0-10, over 20 variables), and a columns with chosen treatment (0/1, over 10 variables).
The dataset include over 1000 records.

Correlation plot seems inconvenient for me.
**I am looking for a statistical test and/or visualization for analysis of associations between declared symptomes and treatment.**

I am coding in R.